# XML Parsing of Password, without storing/caching in db

Tags: ios, xml, xml-parsing

I am in a case were I get a really simple XML body returned, but I want to parse it to a string without storing it anywhere accidentally. And since this is such a simple case, I was wondering what would be the best way of parsing this?

```
<user>
     <password> holla </password>
</user>
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to have a NSURLConnection object and a NSXMLParser object. I'm sure you've already know that.

let's say you have a NSString *tempString somewhere.

For NSXMLParser, here are the methods you have to implement:

```
// When the start of an element is found
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
   namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
  qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
     attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"password"])
    {
        // initialize your string
        tempString = [NSString alloc] init];
    }
}

// When the text in an element is found
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser 
foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    // use the value of the string(password) to initialize your string
    tempString = string;
}

// When the end of element is found
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser 
  didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
   namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
  qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{ 
    // whatever work left to do with the xml parsing
    // use know you get the password string, so do whatever you want after that
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Got the password!"
                                                    message:@"" 
                                                   delegate:nil 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was looking at using this before, just need some affirmation. This is an efficient way to parse a single attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe setting a simple `NSXMLParser` could be very simple.

But, if you need to parse XML throughout your application I suggest you to read about GDataXML. Here a tutorial on [how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml). This parser is very fast and also easy to use.

Hope it helps.